# How to remove lone 1's if followed by any letter with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

**Problem:**

Input: 1b-12

Output: b-2

Desired output: b-12

**Code I am currently using:**

```
Regex.Replace("1b-12", @"\b1(\w+)\b", @"$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Question:**

How do I fix my regex to make 1b = b, but leave 11b as 11b and 11 as 11?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Replace `\w+` with `\p{L}`, `\w` matches digits as well. Use `@"\b1(\p{L})\b"` or `@"\b1(\p{L}+)\b"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `\w` matches letters, digits, underscores and some combining marks, you should use `\p{L}`, or - if you need to only allow ASCII letters - `[a-zA-Z]`.

An example solution that matches `1` at the start of a word and then contains 1+ letters:

```
Regex.Replace("1b-12", @"\b1(?=\p{L}+\b)", "")
Regex.Replace("1b-12", @"\b1(?=[a-zA-Z]+\b)", "")
```

See the regex [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb1%28%3F%3D%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%5Cb%29&i=1b-12&r=). Note you do not need `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` as `\p{L}` and `[a-zA-Z]` match both lower and uppercase letters.

**Details**

- `\b` - here, a start of a word
- `1` - a `1` char
- `(?=\p{L}+\b)` - immediately followed with 1+ letters and then end of word. Also, as this is a lookahead pattern that does not consume chars, your replacement pattern can stay empty.

Comment: Wiktor you're so kind, I was really stuck trying all sorts of replacements for the w+ and just not getting it. Your solution works perfectly and I couldn't have asked for a more excellent reply. Thank you! (I will accept the answer as soon as the timer lets me)

Comment: @Luuk Right you are, it is unspecified. Always the case with *word* boundaries. There are a lot of different solutions, and unless OP needs to cater for any specific scenario, I do not want to pollute the answer with redundant suggestions.